# Remotly Control/Stream Android 11 Screen to PC without having to confirm connection every time

Tags: android, adb, android-11, remote-control

I would like to remotely contol my and my families phones without having to confirm the connection every time.
I bought myself a new mobile phone and with it I changed from Android 9 to 11. But now I run every time into this request, to allow the remote control connection to be established, which could be solved under Android 9 with the don't ask again (for this device) check box and after extensive googleing and searching in the developer tools and other android settings I still cannot loose it.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of it and what sens it could have to ask for the permission every time if you already had to make the connection (over usb at least) possible by activating usb debuging in the developer options first and already added there to permanently trust the device?

The mentioned request:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what is done from the pc that your Android app would be started.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.airdroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044813133-Why-I-can-t-find-don-t-show-again-option-when-grant-casting-permission-for-AirDroid-Personal-Screen-Mirroring-

Google removed the 'Don't show again' option changing from Android 10 to 11.